# Cast instance/reference?

Tags: java, casting, reference, return-value, return-type

Hi I'm a little confused about something.

Lets say I have class A and B. A is the super class of B. If I have a method which has a return type of A, can I use this as a return value:

```
public class test{
    private B b;//remember: A is super class of B so 'public class B extends A'

    public test(){
        b = new B();
    }

    public A geta(){
        return (A)b;
    }
}
```

So that the value returned by 'geta()' will be a reference to an instance of 'b' cast as A so that for example, if A has variable X and B has variable Y i'll be able to do this:

```
test t = new test(); //t.b.X = 5 and t.b.y = 10
A a = t.geta();
a.X = 20 /*This will change the value of X in the instance of B, b, of t...
           in other words, t.b.X will also equal 20*/
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks for your time!

Comment: So far, everything you've said appears to be correct. … But, what's the question?

Comment: Note that you don't need the cast to `A` if `B` is a subclass of `A`. `return b;` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

geta can just `return b;` since b is an A.

Comment: wow I really need to take a break